# Не отображается картинка в инфоблоке. Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

В инфоблоке создаю свойство "Картинка", поле обязательное, код - ATT_MYIMG, Типы загружаемых файлов - изображения. Добавляю инфоблок на страницу, в параметрах компонента в настройках списка указываю отображать код (ATT_MYIMG) и в настройках детального просмотра указываю то же самое. На страницу выводится не сама картинка, а ссылка на неё, нажав на ссылку идет переадресация на пустую страницу с картинкой. Подскажите, как можно сразу выводить картинку, а не ссылку на нее.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в нужном месте в шаблоне компонента в тэг `img` передавайте параметр из массива данных нужного свойста, который отвечает за путь к изображению.

Comment: По подробнее не могли бы вы расписать, потому что, как я понимаю, у меня путь к картинке вставлен верно, проблема в том, что вместо картинки выводится ссылка на неё и мне нужно как то заменить ссылку на само изображение.